# Caliburn.Micro Update 2.0.1 to 2.0.2 went wrong

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

Hi today I decide to update the Caliburn.Micro nuget package.

But since then all my button/control are broken.

No more binding !
Furthermore, every time I'm clicking on a button this exception is throwed.

[image]

```
<Button x:Name="LeftImport" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Width="30" Height="30" BorderThickness="0">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Import</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Import a package</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="White">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_download}" />
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
</Button>
```

**NOTE**
I used Caliburn.Micro.Start to install 2.0.1

I'm out of solution.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be many changes in the 2.0.2 update (https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/releases/tag/2.0.2). Have you tried cleaning out your project, removing all old references and rebuilding?

Comment: Yes and I've rolled back to 2.0.1 and everything run fine... I don't know what is going on with 2.0.2

Comment: Can you append your post to include the XAML of the button that is failing?

Comment: Updated my question but all my button are failing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found my problem in 2.0.1 Caliburn.Micro.Start created his constructor with `StartRuntime();` but in 2.0.2 they added `Initialize();` I changed`StartRuntime();` with `Initialize();` and worked!

[image: 2.0.2]